# How to convert one row text from a result of a query into a string that can be used in another query in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
select value from some_table_name where key='some_key'
```

The result is 1 row only. It is a text with commas

```
apple,banana,orange
```

How can I use that result in this below query?

```
SELECT unnest(
  string_to_array('use above text from query in here', ',')
) AS parts;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the unnest directly in the FROM clause:

```
select u.* 
from some_table_name t
  cross join unnest(string_to_array(t.value, ',')) as u(val)
where t.key='some_key';
```

Or with a current version of Postgres:

```
select u.* 
from some_table_name t
  cross join string_to_table(t.value, ',') as u(val)
where t.key='some_key'
```